# Using Shortcode to Grab Archive Listing, Separate by Year

Tags: php, shortcode, archives

Here's code I've modified to display an archive list of every month I've posted news. Each month of course links to the archive for that month. I can then include the shortcode wherever I like.

```
function my_archives($params, $content = null) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'type' => 'style1'
), $params));

ob_start();
?>

<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>     

<?php return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('archives','my_archives');
```

However, I just cannot figure out from reading the wp_get_archives page (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives) how to organize the list of months with, say, a year heading. So right now the above code outputs like this:

```
<li>June 2014</li>
<li>May 2014</li>
<li>April 2014</li>
etc. etc. etc. for every year and month (my website has been up for 11 years, so that's over 100 links in one blob of a list).
```

I was wondering if it is even possible to change the list to something like this instead:

```
<b><u>2014</u></b><ul>
<li>June 2014</li>
<li>May 2014</li>
etc.</ul>
<b><u>2013</u></b><ul>
<li>December 2014</li>
<li>November 2014</li>
etc.</ul>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer: http://www.stemlegal.com/strategyblog/2011/wordpress-wednesdays-better-archive-lists-in-wordpress/

And the final code looks something like this:

```
function getarchives_filter($where, $args) {
    if (isset($args['year'])) {
    $where .= ' AND YEAR(post_date) = ' . intval($args['year']); }
    return $where;
}
add_filter('getarchives_where', 'getarchives_filter', 10, 2);

function my_archives($params, $content = null) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'type' => 'style1'
    ), $params));

    $currentyear = date('Y');
    $years = range('2012',$currentyear);
    foreach($years as $year){
        $archive = wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly','echo' => 0 ,'year' => $year) );
        if(!empty($archive)){
            echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li>'.$year.'</li>';
            echo $archive;
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }

}
add_shortcode('archives','my_archives');
```

Answer (score 1):

This will output months with a year heading. 11 years is a lot, in the past I've added a simple jQuery [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/), whereby if a user clicks a year they then get the list of months for that year. Just a suggestion.

```
  <?php
    $years = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY post_date DESC");
    foreach($years as $year) {
    ?>

      <a class="year" href="<?php echo get_year_link($year); ?>"><?php echo $year; ?></a>
        <?php   $months = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(post_date) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' AND YEAR(post_date) = '".$year."' ORDER BY post_date DESC");
            foreach($months as $month) {
        ?>
          <a href="<?php echo get_month_link($year, $month); ?>"><?php echo date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month) );?></a>
        <?php } ?>

  <?php } ?>
```